# .NET Decimal.Parse throws a FormatException when using period as thousand separator

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET, can anyone tell me why this works:

```
Decimal.Parse("1,234.56", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

But this throws a System.FormatException?

```
Decimal.Parse("1.234,56", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Is there a recommended approach to parsing European numbers which might contain a period as the thousand separator and a comma as the decimal point?

Thank you!

Comment: Each country has own settings, there isn't european standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The French `CultureInfo`'s `NumberFormatInfo` uses space as the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) - so this works, for example:

```
Decimal.Parse("1 234,56", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

If you want to use `.` as a thousands separator, you'll need a culture where that is the `NumberGroupSeparator`. For example, you could use Spanish:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
        var d = Decimal.Parse("1.234,56", culture);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Or modify another culture:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        // Call clone to make sure it's mutable
        var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR").Clone();
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
        var d = Decimal.Parse("1.234,56", culture);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the MSDN page it seems that the Spanish `CultureInfo`'s `NumberFormatInfo` is using `.`

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx), the correct format for **("fr-FR")** should be:

```
Decimal.Parse("1 234,56", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

which will produce the same output as the above as for **("en-US")**

> 1234.56

Check this example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UTBWuM).